# How to fix "My VM has all the options greyed out and it is not running"

Tags: virtualbox

My VM shut down on Virtualbox - possibly a crash - no solid reason for why it shut down.  I tried to restart it but Start was greyed out along with Clone, Move, Remove, Pause, Reset, Stop, Discard Saved State, Refresh... most all features were greyed out.   I finally went to VBOXMANAGE to clone it using a command line from Windows.  No idea why everything is greyed out.  Rebooting did not help.   I'm not sure what else to do to start the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Close all your Windows.  It is highly likely there is a "switch" popup that wants your attention.   Rebooting your machine may help but if it is a popup, it could still be waiting when you return.  Microsoft puts the windows that were open (mostly) when you shutdown and they could easily re-cover the popup after you reboot.

Comment: Porbably should post this somewhere else.  hmmm, is there more than one stackoverflow?